# Chrome Dev Tools - Is there a way to test responsive w/ rulers without mobile emulation?

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like the ability to enable responsive mode in dev tools to allow for scaling the viewport width and height so as to debug my media queries but without disabling the mouse scroll and hover features, i.e. I only want to adjust the viewport, no other emulation is desired, is this possible?

Update for clarity: I'd like the ability to view the rulers AND adjust the width freely like when device is set to Responsive but without the mobile touch stuff enabled. When creating a new device and choosing Desktop, you lose this functionality.

Update#2 - It appears what I'm asking for cannot be done, I've submitted a feature request - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/5360

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom devices marked as desktop instead of mobile for the various dimensions you'd like to test.

[image: Select "Edit..." from the "Dimensions" drop-down menu.]
[image: "Add custom device..." with "Desktop" selected.]

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but doesn't give me what I'm looking for, when using Desktop as the device, it is fixed at the size you define, you cannot adjust it in the viewer. I've updated my original question to add this clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Responsive mode appears to be the only mode that allows for this but mobile touch mode is enabled, maybe I'm asking the wrong question. How do I disable touch when using Responsive for the device?